# Application calls Begin_Request for images, css and js ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, asp.net-mvc-routing, application-lifecycle, iis-modules

I have this MVC application where I declare the following routings:

```cs
routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;

routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{*pathInfo}");

routes.IgnoreRoute("{*alljs}", new { alljs = @".*\.js(/.*)?" });
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allcss}", new { allcss = @".*\.css(/.*)?" });
```

I deployed my application on IIS and I see that the `Application_BeginRequest` is called also for every static resource

```cs
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Log.Write("Begin request for " + Request.RawUrl)
}
```

I tried to set the `web.Config` in this way:

```cs
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
          <add name="StaticFiles" path="*.js, *.css, *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png" verb="*" type="StaticFileModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="None" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

No success, unfortunately. Anyone has a clue for this?

Comment: Why are you using `BeginRequest`?

Comment: To instantiate the DB session.

Comment: can you configure IIS so that it serves the static files? It won't need to instantiate a asp.net process.

Comment: @Dallas - The StaticFiles handler is invoking the IIS's StaticFileModule, but it doesn't work. I'll be glad if you can address me where I can find an example of this solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application_BeginRequest has nothing to do with routing.
It will always fire for all managed requests.

If you only want to handle MVC requests, use a global action filter.

Comment: You are saying: do not use Begin_Request but use global action filter instead?

Comment: Yes.  Or, better yet, instantiate it lazily when first used.  Or use a non-global filter and apply that filter to each action that needs the DB.